# How to force caret to the next line in contentEditble area

Tags: html, contenteditable

I'd like to use the contentEditable attribute to create an images-only 'editor' that allow users to create images representing text characters.

One problem I've run into is how to display the caret on the next line to start a new row of images. Putting a break tag at the end of the content doesn't move the caret to the next line.

I want the user to click into the 3rd line to start a new row of images - but the caret only appears at the end of the 2nd line - even though I have a break tag at the end. Does anyone have suggestions? I'm out of ideas! Thanks!

Here's a plunk that represents the issue: https://plnkr.co/edit/c2OEwaKOtkgpOzJerAzT?p=preview

```
      <p contenteditable="true" style='text-align:center;'>
        <span>
            <img class='dspItem' style='background-color:red'>
            <img class='dspItem' style='background-color:green'>
        </span>
        <br>
        <span>
            <img class='dspItem' style='background-color:blue'>
            <img class='dspItem' style='background-color:purple'>
        </span>
        <br>
      </p>
```

And the CSS:

```
.dspItem {
  display: inline;
  float: none;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 30px;
}
p {
    height: 200px;
    padding: 0;
   border: thin solid #ff0000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added a `return` function at the bottom of the `<script>` block. This function will wrap a div in front of the caret and one div wrapped around the content behind the caret. Found it in this [article](http://wadmiraal.net/lore/2012/06/14/contenteditable-hacks-returning-like-a-pro/). Provided are 2 of the same demo in <kbd>[**PLUNKER**](http://embed.plnkr.co/NjWmdvr8pjypPjJOUcvV/)</kbd> and the other a Snippet.

#### SNIPPET

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <style>
    fieldset {
      margin: 20px auto;
    }
    input {
      width: 5ex;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 1px 3px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="editor1" contenteditable="true">
    <br/>123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
    <br/>12 45678 abcd fg ijk mnopqrst vwxyz
    <br/>123 5 789a cde ghijklm o qrst v xyz
    <br/>12345 789abcd fg ijklmnopq s u wxyz
    <br/>123 567 9abc efg ijklm op rst vwxy
    <br/>1 34 6789a cdef hij lm opq stuvwxyz
    <br/>1 3456 89a cd fghij l no qrst vwx z
    <br/>12 4 6789 bcd fgh j lmno q stuv xy
  </div>
  <fieldset>

    <input type="button" class="fontStyle" onclick="document.execCommand('italic',false,null);" value="I" title="Italicize Highlighted Text">
    <input type="button" class="fontStyle" onclick="document.execCommand('bold',false,null);" value="B" title="Bold Highlighted Text">
    <input id="row" name="row" placeholder="Row#" />
    <input id="col" name="col" placeholder="Col#" />
    <button id="btn">Focus</button>
  </fieldset>
  <p>Each row has a number of non-repeated string of alphanumeric characters:</p>
  <pre><code>123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</code></pre>
  <p>Maximum of 35 characters. Every row except the first row has some missing characters and in their place is a whitespace.
  </p>
  <script>
    function setCaret(x, y) {
      var ele = document.getElementById("editor1");
      var rng = document.createRange();
      var sel = window.getSelection();
      var row = parseInt(x, 10) * 2;
      var col = parseInt(y, 10);
      rng.setStart(ele.childNodes[row], col);
      rng.collapse(true);
      sel.removeAllRanges();
      sel.addRange(rng);
      ele.focus();
    }


    var btn = document.getElementById('btn');

    btn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      var rowSet = document.getElementById('row').value;
      var colSet = document.getElementById('col').value;
      setCaret(rowSet, colSet);
    }, true);
/* onReturn ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~*/
    var onReturn = function(e) {

      if (window.getSelection) {
        e.stopPropagation();

        var selection = window.getSelection(),
          range = selection.getRangeAt(0),
          br = document.createElement('br');
        range.deleteContents();
        range.insertNode(br);
        range.setStartAfter(br);
        range.setEndAfter(br);
        range.collapse(false);
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);

        return false;
      }
      return true;
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```